# SQL - Select latest messages on a chat table

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm currently trying to make an online chat with Ajax and the messages are sent via a php file to my database. I would like to be able to list all the conversations where a user is involved. Let's take this as an example : 
[exemple of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INWgZ.png)

I would like to list the conversations ordered from the most recent one to the oldest.

I should have conversation with user 25846.... since it's the last message, then with 10206...... and finally with 11627.....

My desired output is a table of 3 records with the fields ID_to and content_msg, order as above.
This is the current SQL request i'm trying :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_to 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM messages 
    WHERE ID_to = 1140816689329214 OR ID_from = 1140816689329214 
    ORDER BY timestamp_msg DESC
    ) as tmp
```

Even with this the output is not in the right order, and I can't understand why since I have a order by on my request.

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering is determined by the `ORDER BY` in the *outermost* query.  Ordering in subqueries doesn't matter.

This would seem to be what you want:

```
SELECT id_to
FROM messages 
WHERE ID_to = 1140816689329214 OR ID_from = 1140816689329214 
GROUP BY id_to
ORDER BY MAX(timestamp_msg) DESC;
```

Comment: Well thank you very much that solved my problem. This was the order in the subqueries that was useless then. Thank you and have a great day, will accept the answer in 10 min